# Access dynamic QML objects from C++

Tags: qml

Is anyone aware of how to access and store dynamically created QML objects from C++?
I used the following code suggested on Qt Site for creating dynamic QML objects and trying to store them in a [QML list type](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-list.html)

```
    property list<Button> listButtons: [
        Button{ }
    ]
    function addButton(buttonname) {
        console.log("Creating Pin: "+buttonname)
        var component = Qt.createComponent("Button.qml");
        if (component.status == Component.Ready)
        {
            var newbutton = component.createObject(node);
            newbutton.x = 20;
            newbutton.y = 30;
            listButtons.append(newbutton) //I get a error here: listButtons.append [undefined] is not a function
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Unable to create button: "+buttonname)
        }
     }
```

Thank you.

CV

Answer (score 2):

There is documentation regarding this. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qml-list.html

To achieve this you need to implement an array as a list

```
import QtQuick 1.0
import "script.js" as JsScript

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360

    function getList(){
        return JsScript.array;
    }

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Hello World"
    }
    Item {
     Component.onCompleted: {
         console.log('complemented');
         JsScript.addItem('abc')
         console.log("Added:", JsScript.array[0])
     }
    }
}
```

**script.js**

```
var array = new Array();

function  getArray(){
    return array;
}
    function addItem(item) {
     array.push(item)
    }
```

from c++

```
QDeclarativeEngine engine;
QDeclarativeComponent component(&engine, "MyItem.qml");
QObject *object = component.create();

QVariant returnedValue;
QVariant msg = "Hello from C++";
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, "myQmlFunction",
     Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariant, returnedValue),
     Q_ARG(QVariant, msg));

returnedValue.toList();
```

Untested code.
hmmm, i am not sure about this.But maybe QVariant.toList() will work or maybe it wont.You'll have to try.

Comment: Sry, I shud've mentioned, I was looking for accessing these objects in C++. How can I access "myArray" from a C++ application?